# Hacia atrás y hacia adelante

Tags: java

Tengo un sistema donde trabajo con una tabla (JTable, visual) en donde se modifican sus valores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello, el usuario interactua con la vista el cual desencadena una serie de consultas SQL.

Lo que necesito hacer, es algo parecido a las funcionalidad que poseen los editores de texto (*excel, word, etc*), un "*deshacer*" y "*hacer*" (Ctrl + Z - Ctrl Y).

Trabajo en **Java** con **JDBC**, y por cada A.B.M. en dicha tabla, establezco un **Savepoint** (llamemosle "Savepoint 1") antes de concretar la operación y luego prosigo. Esto me ayuda para hacer el "atras" posteriormente.

Cuando le doy al boton "atras", el sistema retrotrae al punto de guardado que establecí en su momento, pero aqui viene lo bueno. **No puedo "volver" hacia "adelante" (Ctrl + Y)**.

Intenté estableciendo otro Savepoint (llamemoslo "Savepoint 2") en el estado "siguiente" antes de abandonarlo para luego poder volver, pero como ese "Savepoint 2" fue establecido a partir del "Savepoint 1", al haber retrotraido al "Savepoint 1" el "Savepoint 2" fue desecho.

**¿Cómo puedo establecer un punto de guardado para volver "hacia adelante"?**

**¿Que me recomiendan?**

Comment: Supongo que guardas los SavePoints en un objeto y al "volver atrás" te desaparece. Has pensado en guardarlos en algún tipo de fichero externo que no desaparezca al volver atrás? Así lo podrías recuperar.

Comment: Mmmm... no me cierra del todo. Pero me brindarías una biografía de donde pueda informarme para ver un poco mas sobre eso?

Comment: Para escribir ficheros ahí tienes: http://www.chuidiang.org/java/ficheros/ObjetosFichero.php